# Case sensitive for yii framework

Tags: javascript, php, yii

I have some script from yii that after configuration, it throws an error like this:

```
Alias "application.components.HFooter" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing PHP file and the file is readable.

/var/www/rumah/framework/YiiBase.php(322)

310         if($isClass && (class_exists($className,false) || interface_exists($className,false)))
311             return self::$_imports[$alias]=$className;
312 
313         if(($path=self::getPathOfAlias($alias))!==false)
314         {
315             if($isClass)
316             {
317                 if($forceInclude)
318                 {
319                     if(is_file($path.'.php'))
320                         require($path.'.php');
321                     else
322                         throw new CException(Yii::t('yii','Alias "{alias}" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing PHP file and the file is readable.',array('{alias}'=>$alias)));
323                     self::$_imports[$alias]=$className;
324                 }
325                 else
326                     self::$classMap[$className]=$path.'.php';
327                 return $className;
328             }
329             else  // a directory
330             {
331                 if(self::$_includePaths===null)
332                 {
333                     self::$_includePaths=array_unique(explode(PATH_SEPARATOR,get_include_path()));
334                     if(($pos=array_search('.',self::$_includePaths,true))!==false)
```

It runs well and good under Windows, but under Linux it does not work. I suspect that the cause is related to `case sensitive`. How to solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in your `\application\components` directory

and type the correct fileaneme  `HFooter.php`

```
 application.components.HFooter
```

Comment: thanks it work, but when im try base browse link not found. at windows its found, idk where is url path for yii.

Comment: Yii1 or Yii2 please ( seem Yii1)  ?  show me the related link pelase ? anyway if the code worl mean that i answer right to your question .. is fair then mark my answer as accepted and eventually post another question for new questions ..

Comment: yes your answer right, sorry im still new on stackoverflow, btw its still on localhost. so can you guest what happen thanks.

Comment: update you question and show me exactly the url you provided .. for call the controller\action you need and  you controller   actionName definition  code ..?

Answer (score 0):

ur right. in linux names of files and commands are case-sensitive unlike windows. so to solve it you can either rename file you try to include or type filename with correct case. 
in your case you should check application.components.HFooter file. likely it has name smth. like Hfooter.php of hfooter.php